# Forwarding a customized string through class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to forward a customized string which i have in my class mediator to the client who have invoked the process and i'm unable to figure out how that is done.
So please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Class mediator can modify the message and append custom data into the message. [This sample](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample380) shows how to add a string to the message using a class mediator.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your string to the payload message. Then this can send as the response. Please have a look at here[1]

[1] http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/generating-simple-response-using-wso2-enterprise-service-bus